# Is the Exsheet package still under development?

Tags: exsheets, xsim

I prefer use Exsheet.I know Exsheet been replaced by a XSIM package, but is the Exsheet package still under development?

Comment: I guess [cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049) is the best person to answer this, though he might just say the same as he wrote in the [`exsheets` description on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets): "As of May 2017, this package has been superseded by its official successor xsim. exsheets itself is now considered obsolete, but will stay alive, and will continue to receive bugfix releases. However, new features will not be added any more."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: `exsheets` is effectively frozen. It can of course be used as it is and if bugs are found or appear because of development of packages it depends on or something similar then these bugs will get fixed if possible. However, `exsheets` is not actively developed. That means no new features will be added and no substantial changes will be made, feature requests are pointless.